# Kendo upload validation message position

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-validator

I am using kendo uplaod,and want validate uploaded file size.

`<form id="uploadForm" method="post" action="{{url}}">
      <div class="demo-section k-content">
         <input name="files" id="files" type="file" />
         <p style="padding-top: 1em; text-align: right">
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Select " class="k-button k-primary" />
         </p>
    </div>
</form>`

and 
    `$("#uploadForm").kendoValidator({
            messages: {
                custom: "Please enter valid  size file",
            },
            rules: {
                custom: function (e: any) {
                  return ...;
                }
            },
            validateOnBlur: false
        });`

Everything is ok,but message appears on 'Select files; input.How change position of error message? I want show message under  file as output.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this fiddle I created, hope it will help you

```
**http://jsfiddle.net/keshann/Lyz49ryn/**
```

Comment: Can you help me for this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848910/kendovalidator-acces-to-angular2-component-property