# kendoValidator acces to Angular2 component property

Tags: validation, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-validator

I am using Kendo Upload in my Angular 2 application.I have inject servcie for **error message** and file  **permissible size**,but when **KendoValidator** called,  **this.service** is already **undefined**.

```
 export class MyUpload implements AfterViewInit {

  private message:string="message error":


    constructor() {
    }



    ngAfterViewInit(): any {
         $("#files").kendoUpload({
            multiple: false

        });
        $("#uploadForm").kendoValidator({
            messages: {
                fileSize: message
            },
            rules: {
                fileSize: function (e: any) {

                   return ....;
                }
            },
            validateOnBlur: false
        });
    }
```

How can I use this.service for getting size and message?

Comment: The issue in your code could be a scope issue. Have you tried using `console.log(this)` where this error occurs? My guess here is that you are in the scope of the `Validator` or the `Upload`. Btw. you might want to have a look at the `Angular2` implementation of `KendoUI`. (http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/).

Comment: I check console.log(this), this is not a instance of my angular component.
And how get angular   **service** instance ?

Comment: You might be missing '@injectable' decorator becasuse I see its not injecting properly

Comment: Dear Spark,sorry for answering late. I updated question,the injectable is not reson for  error.
Now I want read property of class,and it is undefined too.